# ant: handling jar whose contents have file permissions 000

Tags: java, ant, installation, jar, file-permissions

I am trying to overwrite the default icon of installer JAR created by IzPack, with one from my application:

```
<jar update="yes"
  jarfile="${pwd}/dist/${release}_installer.jar">
  <zipfileset src="${pwd}/dist/app.jar" includes="com/izforge/izpack/panels/**"/>
  <zipfileset src="${pwd}/dist/app.jar"
      includes="com/xyz/img/logo.png" fullpath="img/JFrameIcon.png"/>
</jar>
```

This task works in an ordinary JAR file, but the `img` folder of the installer JAR appears to have 0-0-0 file permissions on it, such that if I extract it (notice no `r`s or `w`s):

```
$ ll
---------- 1 bguiz staff  742 2004-05-29 11:39 JFrameIcon.png
```

This also means that my ant task above execute, but fails to replace the required file. Is there any way to work around this?

---

NOTE:

Constrained to using Ant 1.7.1, thus the `preserve0permissions` attribute of the `jar` task is unavailable.